# C# replace null XML node with respective data type's default value

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

i have to iterate a loop on about 400 different XML files and every time i will be getting different xml file.

I have about 11 nodes in the XML(all coming as `String`) and i am parsing this XML and storing the XML Element's values using Entity Framework in the Database (in different data types like `Decimal`, `int`, `string`, `double`)

I do not know which xml node will come as null and i do not want to add a null check for each and every node..

***Is there a way to implement a common null check for the whole XML file*** in the loop so if any node comes as null, i can assign it to the default value of respective data type in its respective Entity.. Some thing like the code snippet shown below:-

```
foreach (XmlNode node in tableElements)
{
    dcSearchTerm searchTermEntity = new dcSearchTerm();
    //Reference keywords: creation & assignment
    int IDRef = 0, salesRef = 0, visitsRef = 0, saleItemsRef = 0;
    DateTime visitDateRef = new DateTime();
    decimal revenueRef = 0;

    int.TryParse(node["id"].InnerText, out IDRef);
    searchTermEntity.SearchTerm = node["Search_x0020_Term"].InnerText;
    searchTermEntity.ReferrerDomain = node["Referrer_x0020_Domain"].InnerText;

    if (node["Country"] == null)
    {
        searchTermEntity.Country = "";
    }
    else
    {
        searchTermEntity.Country = node["Country"].InnerText;
    }

    DateTime.TryParse(node["Visit_x0020_Date"].InnerText, out visitDateRef);
    searchTermEntity.VisitEntryPage = node["Visit_x0020_Entry_x0020_Page"].InnerText;
    int.TryParse(node["Sales"].InnerText, out salesRef);
    int.TryParse(node["Visits"].InnerText, out visitsRef);

    decimal.TryParse(node["Revenue"].InnerText, out revenueRef);
    int.TryParse(node["Sale_x0020_Items"].InnerText, out saleItemsRef);

    // assigning reference values to the entity
    searchTermEntity.ID = IDRef;
    searchTermEntity.VisitDate = visitDateRef;
    searchTermEntity.Sales = salesRef;
    searchTermEntity.Visits = visitsRef;
    searchTermEntity.Revenue = revenueRef;
    searchTermEntity.SaleItems = saleItemsRef;
    searches.Add(searchTermEntity);

    return searches;
}
```

P.S.:- This is my first question on SO, please feel free to ask more details 
       Waiting for a flood of suggestions ! :)

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you using? If you are using .NET 3.5+ you code could be much simplified by using generics / extension methods.

Comment: I'm usually an advocate of doing things on the code side, but if you are shipping this over to the database anyways, you could parse it there using OPENXML command. Not only is parsing it as simple as defining the xpath to the node, but with default values on your table you can easily fallback on the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here is extension class that adds methods to Strings and XmlNodes:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    // obviously these ToType methods can be implemented with generics
    // to further reduce code duplication
    public static int ToInt32(this string value)
    {
        Int32 result = 0;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            Int32.TryParse(value, out result);

        return result;
    }
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this string value)
    {
        Decimal result = 0M;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            Decimal.TryParse(value, out result);

        return result;
    }

    public static int GetInt(this XmlNode node, string key)
    {
        var str = node.GetString(key);
        return str.ToInt32();
    }

    public static string GetString(this XmlNode node, string key)
    {
        if (node[key] == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(node[key].InnerText))
            return null;
        else
            return node.InnerText;
    }

    // implement GetDateTime/GetDecimal as practice ;)
}
```

Now we can rewrite your code like:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in tableElements)
{
    // DECLARE VARIABLES WHEN YOU USE THEM
    // DO NOT DECLARE THEM ALL AT THE START OF YOUR METHOD
    // http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them

    dcSearchTerm searchTermEntity = new dcSearchTerm()
    {
        ID = node.GetInt("id"),
        SearchTerm = node.GetString("Search_x0020_Term"),
        ReferrerDomain = node.GetString("Referrer_x0020_Domain"),
        Country = node.GetString("Country"),
        VisitDate = node.GetDateTime("Visit_x0020_Date"),
        VisitEntryPage = node.GetString("Visit_x0020_Entry_x0020_Page"),
        Sales = node.GetInt("Sales"),
        Visits = node.GetInt("Visits"),
        Revenue = node.GetDecimal("Revenue"),
        SaleItems = node.GetDecimal("Sale_x0020_Items")
    };

    searches.Add(searchTermEntity);

    return searches;
}
```

Don't forget to implement GetDateTime and GetDecimal extensions- I've left those to you ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a monad style extension method like below. The sample provided acts only on structs. You can modify it to use for all types.

```
public static class NullExtensions
{
    public delegate bool TryGetValue<T>(string input, out T value);

    public static T DefaultIfNull<T>(this string value, TryGetValue<T> evaluator, T defaultValue) where T : struct
    {
        T result;

        if (evaluator(value, out result))
            return result;

        return defaultValue;
    }

    public static T DefaultIfNull<T>(this string value, TryGetValue<T> evaluator) where T : struct
    {
        return value.DefaultIfNull(evaluator, default(T));
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
string s = null;
bool result = s.DefaultIfNull<bool>(bool.TryParse, true);
int r = s.DefaultIfNull<int>(int.TryParse);
```